# Dependency in Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I am very new to Cucumber and I have a situation where I have to run a certain Scenario A present in Feature A before I can run Scenario B present in Feature B. I am wondering how can I do this in cucumber, I have used @After and @Before in a feature but how can I take care of cross feature dependencies like this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That sounds like a codesmell - features are supposed to be independent.

Comment: would not "Manage Profile" depend on "Registration" feature?

Answer (score 5):

Your scenarios must be independent (like any kind of tests be it acceptance tests, unit tests etc.). Never make assumptions about the order of tests/specs.

If you need to perform common operations before and after each scenario (or each scenario tagged with tag), use `Before` and `After` hooks.

If you need to do same initialization before each scenario in the feature and you want *to be explicit about this initialization in the text of your `Feature`*, you can use `Background`:

```
Feature: some feature

  Background: logged in
    Given I am logged in as administrator

  Scenario: some scenario where user will be logged in
```

*Note:* `Before` hooks run before `Backgrounds`

Comment: thanks a lot Alex, this was very very useful and educating. I have one last question, similar to background if I wanted to execute a scenario after all the scenarios in a feature have been executed, how is this typically done in Cucumber. For example TestNG has a tag called @AfterClass. It is basically like a tear down, or for example I made some changes to the state of an account, now in this last scenario, i want to bring the account back to the original state.

Comment: Usually teardown (and setup) logic is an implementation details and is implemented in *Before*, *After* or **Around** hooks (because reader of your spec won't need to know about these technical things). You can read more about cucumber hooks [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks). `Background` is useful when you provide common customer-readable (non technical) background for your scenarious. `Background` have no inverse method. Some advices from cucumber developers for `Background` usage are written [here].(https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Background).